# Close overlay on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, overlay

I am using the [codrops](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/09/30/animated-border-menus/) border menu overlay and I wanted to find a way for the user to close an overlay on scroll. As of now, a user can click an overlay  on a desktop or mobile to close it, but scrolling will just scroll the body underneath. I want it to instead close the overlay.

The overlay has an event listener, but it is only for click, not for body scroll. Is there a way to add a listener for body scroll to the overlay as well?

```
overlay.addEventListener( eventtype, closeClickFn );
```

Above adds an event listener to the overlay that says: on click/mobile touch, close the overlay.

Comment: Have you tried adding your own event to close it on scroll?

Comment: @JustinWood, I am not sure exactly how that would work. Do you want me to add another event listener? Can you give an example? Thanks!

Comment: Do exactly what you have shown us. just use the scroll event type

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can attach to scroll event and then tricker a click to the codrops.

```
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
    $('yourCodrop').click();
});
```

Comment: Yeah I just had to play around with it for a bit. Thanks got it!

Answer (score 0):

Use .scroll method from jquery

http://api.jquery.com/scroll/